# git push throws an error "bash: line 0: echo: write error: No such file or directory". How can I resolve this error?

Tags: git, git-push

I have been using git without any errors for past few months. 
However, now, when I do git push, I get the following error:
"bash: line 0: echo: write error: No such file or directory"
How can this error be resolved ?

Comment: What is the exact command you did, and have any of your local or repo settings changed recently?

Comment: In addition to @TimBiegeleisen's question: Is this all repositories or just one? Do you have any project specific or global `pre-push` git hooks setup?

Comment: Sorry guys, I reinstalled git and that solved the problem. 
No, no local repo settings changed recently.

Comment: for visualstudio.com   there was a git user/password prompt that i didn't see with clicking too fast and that seemed to be the reason for the error for me.

Comment: i had this problem. And the solution for me was just restart the terminal.